# How to display together a shapefile (country basemap) and points (from CSV) via geopandas?

Tags: python, point, csv, geopandas, anaconda

So, I wrote this code that tries to do it but I end up with the map and points being displayed separately

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point
import fiona
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loadPoint():
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\imper\Documents\new_GISfiles\earthquakesPH\emscPhilippines2008to2020_lonLat.csv')
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)]
    crs = {'init': 'epsg:32651'} 
    geo_df = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

    geo_df.to_file(driver='ESRI Shapefile', filename='eqpts.shp')

def plotPoint():
    map = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\imper\Documents\new_GISfiles\earthquakesPH\PH_provs.shp')
    map.plot(cmap = 'jet', column = 'NAME_1', figsize=(10,10))

    pt = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\imper\Documents\new_GISfiles\earthquakesPH\eqpts.shp')
    pt.plot()

loadPoint()
plotPoint()
```

[image]

Comment: You actually asked for two plot instances; one using `map.plot()` and the other using `pt.plot()`. Once an instace is launched, you can reuse it if you assign an [axis](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) variable to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `plot()` method creates a `matplotlib` figure and returns an `ax` object by default. If you want to create just one figure and plot multiple geometries on it, you have to specify the `ax` parameter. For example:

```py
ax = map.plot(cmap = 'jet', column = 'NAME_1', figsize=(10,10))  # keep ax object in a variable
pt.plot(ax=ax)  # specify ax argument
```

Make sure, of course, that your layers share the same spatial reference. See the [`geopandas` mapping tools documentation](https://geopandas.org/mapping.html#maps-with-layers) for more details on plotting several layers in the same figure.

---

On another note, `map` is a function in Python and its name is reserved. It is convenient to avoid naming your variables after such functions.